# Change controller on the fly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 3 controllers and 2 divs in my main angular application. Let's say the left and right div and controller A, B, and C. At start, I set the left div with controller A and the right div with controller B. I want to add a button that change the left div to use controller C and run it. Is this possible? I have stuck with it for three days. I think it's a simple problem because it's just a matter of changing the controller and re-run the new controller.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest for you to try AngularUI Router: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

In your case you could have two states, which both have the same template, but different controllers.

Example:

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('route1', {
      url: "/route1",
      views: {
        "viewA": {
           templateUrl: "templates/a.html",
           controller: "AController"
        },
        "viewB": {
           templateUrl: "templates/b.html",
           controller: "BController"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('route2', {
      url: "/route2",
                views: {
        "viewA": {
           templateUrl: "templates/a.html",
           controller: "CController"
        },
        "viewB": {
           templateUrl: "templates/b.html",
           controller: "BController"
        }
      }
    })
});
```

Comment: Thank you. In my case, the template and controller also different. Yesterday, I tried with angular route. It works, but it reload both left and right. I just need load one of them. For example, for route inbox, I will display it in left and for another function in right. Is it possible? I'm new to angularjs.

Comment: I think it is possible to make one of the views not to reload, but in this case the state, which will not be reloaded has to be a parent state for the other state. That means, that left div template has to be inside right div template (using ui-view directive).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I'm stated it wrong. Both view is dynamically changing but depend on the menu. If some menu clicked, it will update the left side. If another, it will update the right. Maybe you could imagine it like an email viewer. The left is for the list and the right is for the content which in the left clicked. But, it add a menu which can display another "page" in left or right. Basically, if some menu clicked, I just want to define which side will be updated and which content will be displayed.

Comment: You should take a look at nested states: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views

If that does not help you I don't think there is an easy way to do what you want with AngularJS